# Validating two strings

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to validate two strings via TextUtils.isEmpty but i'm failing everytime.

**Following is my code:**

```
    private void addArtist() {
    //getting the values to save
    String email = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String mobileno = editTextName1.getText().toString().trim();

    //checking if the value is provided
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){

        //if the value is not given displaying a toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

     else{

        //getting a unique id using push().getKey() method
        //it will create a unique id and we will use it as the Primary Key for our Artist
        String id = databaseArtists.push().getKey();

        //creating an Artist Object
        Artist artist = new Artist(id, email, mobileno);

        //Saving the Artist
        databaseArtists.child(id).setValue(artist);


        Toast.makeText(this, "Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

Currently this code is working on string email, i want it to work with string mobileno also.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In what way are you failing?  An error?

Comment: Unable to do so.

Comment: You mean, your code isn't doing what it supposed to, but you're not getting an error?  If that's the case, I can't see any code where you're actually checking `mobileno`.

Comment: Its a original code i haven't posted my test code

Comment: I can't help if I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try to use try catch block and inside it try to convert this string after you read from TextField control object into number if "Mobileno" variable should be int type? If it fails then you can in catch block make some other instructions to prevent from inserting it to field of specific object. Have you tried that?